# Plot of roots in the complex plane

Tags: polynomials, roots

What is the best mathematical program that allowes you to find and plot complex roots of polynomials?

Comment: Why do you need the "best" program do do that? What is your typical polynomial?

Comment: At least some that allowes you to do that.

Comment: Try [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=complex+roots+of++z%5E5-z%2B1%3D0).

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=xhblmt) is python code for the polynomial $z^5 - z + 1$:

```
import numpy as np

r = np.roots([1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1])
print('The roots are:', r)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axhline(y=0, color='black')
ax.axvline(x=0, color='black')
ax.scatter(r.real, r.imag, color='blue')

plt.savefig('foo.png')

plt.show()
```

[image]